# Are telegram bot's delay for production?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

According to telegram bot [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq): "**The API will not allow more than 30 messages per second**" and "**The API will not allow bulk notifications to more than ~30 users per second**"
I have connected bot to my python web app and there I am using a for loop, to iterate over list of users who have subscribed to my bot, to send messages to each of them. If I have more than 30 users is it a good idea to cause some delay (using sleep() ) of about 1 second between each iteration of loop to bypass above limitation. Currently my app is under development so I can't test it, so can anyone tell me is it a good strategy or there is some better method available or I shouldn't be using telegram bot for production? 

**UPDATE** After experimenting, I found out that each call to sendMessage is taking ~0.8 sec to complete on my local machine . So should I care about limit of 30 message/sec or 30 users/sec

Comment: The documentation you linked says exactly that it's a good idea to spread out such bulk messages... I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: @AKX documentation says delay of 8-12 hr .So I am asking will the delay of 1 second will work?

Comment: That seems fine, however, a quick thought on design would be to have a worker (perhaps a thread) which consumes a queue of messages to produce while delaying whatever interval to prevent blocking the main process.

Comment: It says "spreading them out to 8 to 12 hours". Obviously you don't need to wait that long if you only have a handful of users.

Comment: @AKX I am developing it for schools so I can expect my user count to go up to 1000 per school, so I was asking that  since 1 second sleep() per iteration can cause huge delay, so is there any efficient way in python for dealing with this type of situation, something which can take care above two limitations of api.

Comment: I would enqueue the messages to be sent in e.g. a database and have another process go through the backlog in a way that takes care not to use too much of that 30-message-per-second quota.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sleep()` is ok, but it will not guarantee a good result in long term.

I would suggest you to have a queue that will limit sending more than 30 messages/second. Here is an [example how to implement that queue](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Avoiding-flood-limits) in case if you use [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) for its development.

Otherwise, you can have some of the following issues:

- sending more messages than limit in parallel process/thread/worker that is not part of bulk;
- too big time to send >1000 messages (it is 17 minutes already);
- issue that bot can be not able to respond during that time to general updates

and so on.